# When click on modal link, "b.preventDefault is not a function" appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, preventdefault

I am working on Rails with haml format, and I have a table which has in the last column a button (link) that launches a modal:

```
= link_to('#', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#team_modal', 'data-project' => project.id) do %span {
    class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks',
    'aria-hidden' => 'true',
    'aria-hidden' => 'true',
    'data-toggle' => "tooltip",
    'title' => 'Team',
    'data-project' => project.id
}
```

When I click on it, the modal shows up, then the following error also appears at the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.preventDefault is not a function
 b.hide @ bootstrap.min.js?body=1:7
 b.toggle @ bootstrap.min.js?body=1:7
 (anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js?body=1:7
 jQuery.extend.each @ jquery.js?body=1:612
 jQuery.fn.jQuery.each @ jquery.js?body=1:242
 a.fn.modal @ bootstrap.min.js?body=1:7
 (anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js?body=1:7
 jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?body=1:3059
 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle @ jquery.js?body=1:2677
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you, by pure hazard, have both the bootstrap script (`bootstrap`) and the minimized bootstrap (`bootstrap.min`) script of required in your `application.js` file?

Comment: You also have `'aria-hidden' => 'true'` twice, though I'm not sure if that's the proper way.

Comment: @BishopBarber I have found this lines in `application.js` : 
`config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.css"
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.min.css"
...
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.js"
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.min.js"`

Comment: @BishopBarber I just noticed that after the last line that I wrote in my comment, there is `config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.js"` again.

Comment: Yeah, be aware of the duplications. If you removed that last line it worked?

Comment: I does not, nor deleting the min file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, finally I removed the duplications like:

```
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.js
```

beside this, I removed the pure scripts and kept the minimal scripts, given:

```
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.css"
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.min.css"
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.js"
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.min.js"
```

to have this:

```
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.min.css"
config.assets.precompile << "redesign/bootstrap.min.js"
```

**Note:** I don't know what this does but it works. If someone knows why keeping the minimal scripts the error desappear, please comment it.

Comment: the reason is obvious, you are creating twice the same event handlers, so code is executing twice..